# Drupal 8: How to get the ['third_party_settings'] of an image field inside hook_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables)

Tags: 8

I have a custom module that requires that I pass variables to my image-formatter template via `hook_preprocess_hook()`, in this case `hook_preprocess_image_formatter()`.

From within the preprocessor, I would like to acquire `$field_display['third_party_settings']['My_Module']`

I should be able to do that by exposing the `#view_mode` and the `#field_name` of the ImageObject I am preprocessing. I may even be able to hard-code `#view_mode = 'full'` in which case all I need to do is exposed the `#field_name` in my processor to acquire the ['third_party_settings']. Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I will be heavily depending on the data that is contained in the image object that is contained within `$variables['item']` to acquire the info needed for this. A gist of part of that object can be found at the following url with data containing the `field_name`: https://gist.github.com/awasson/55ad5da56076e5cb57dd8f3aa68a05f0

Thanks!

Comment: So on further thought, the value I am looking for is nested in the field_storage object in the FieldStorageConfig. I'm just not sure how I can access this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is pretty specific, it may help someone else with a similar problem.

The answer is in getFieldDefinition() object of $variables['item'].

In order to acquire the field name of an image object from within HOOK_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) which is a variation of HOOK_preprocess_HOOK(), you would use:

`$field_name = $variables['item']->getFieldDefinition()->getName();`

Used within the context of a module file it would look something like the following:

`/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 * This allows us to pass attributes to the image_formatter template.
 */
 function MY_MODULE_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {
   // Get the field name
   $field_name = $variables['item']->getFieldDefinition()->getName();
 }`